# Understanding the Covariance and Loading Matrices in Confirmatory Factor Analysis

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, factor-analysis, covariance-matrix, latent-variable

I am currently stuck on how to correctly formulate the model for Confirmatory Factor Analysis(CFA).

The general formula is $Y = \Lambda \xi + \epsilon$. According to Wikipedia $Y$ is a $p \times 1$ matrix of observed random variables. $\Lambda$ is $p \times k$ matrix where $k$ is the number of latent factors. In my case I am interested in a single latent factor so k is 1. I have included screen shots of where I am getting my information underneath to make it easier to see what I am misunderstanding.
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmatory_factor_analysis):

> In confirmatory factor analysis, researchers are typically interested
> in studying the degree to which responses on a $p \times 1$ vector of
> observable random variables can be used to assign a value to one or
> more unobserved variable(s) $\eta$. The investigation is largely
> accomplished by estimating and evaluating the loading of each item
> used to tap aspects of the unobserved latent variable. That is, $y_i$
> is the vector of observed responses predicted by the unobserved latent
> variable $\xi$  , which is defined as:
> $$Y = \Lambda \xi  + \epsilon$$,
> where $Y$ is the $p \times 1$ vector of observed random
> variables, $\xi$  are the unobserved latent
> variables and $\Lambda$  is a $p x k$ matrix
> with $k$ equal to the number of latent variables. Since, $Y$
> are imperfect measures of $\xi$, the model also consists of error, $\epsilon$. Estimates in the maximum likelihood (ML) case generated by iteratively minimizing the fit function,
> $$
> F_{ml} = \log |\Lambda \Omega \Lambda^\prime + I − diag(\Lambda \Omega \Lambda^\prime)| + tr(R(\Lambda \Omega \Lambda^\prime+ I − diag(\Lambda \Omega \Lambda^\prime) − 1 ) − ln(R) ⁡
> $$
> where $\Lambda \Omega \Lambda^\prime + I − diag⁡(\Lambda \Omega \Lambda^\prime)$ is the variance-covariance matrix implied by the proposed
> factor analysis model $R$ is the observed variance-covariance
> matrix.That is, values are found for free model parameters that
> minimize the difference between the model-implied variance-covariance
> matrix and observed variance-covariance matrix.

My data is currently 25000 rows across 5 columns of interest i.e. 25000x5. The wiki clearly states that Y is a p x 1 vector. Given that this equation is clearly similar to multiple linear regression, I am assuming the wiki is going of that premise. A px1 vector does not make sense for my data as far as I can see. Therefore, I would assume instead of multiple linear regression it would be a multivariate linear regression formation so, my Y would need to be a 25000x5 matrix. As such, my $\Lambda$ is 25000x5 where each column represents the how that variable loads onto my latent factor. The latent factor, $\xi$ would thus have to be a matrix of dimensions 5x5.

The next step in CFA is to calculate the model covariance matrix. This is needed because the whole concept of CFA is to find a model covariance matrix that minimizes the difference between the model covariance matrix and the data covariance matrix. Obviously, if I have 5 columns the data covariance matrix would be 5x5. The [UCLA tutorial on CFA](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/seminars/rcfa/) makes it a easier to see how to calculate the covariance matrix.

> Historically, factor analysis is used to answer the question, how much
> common variance is shared among the items. This variance-covariance
> matrix can be described using the model-implied covariance matrix .
> Note that this is in contrast to the observed population covariance
> matrix
>
> which comes only from the data. The formula for the model-implied
> covariance matrix is:
>
> The following describes each parameter, defined as a term in the model
> to be estimated:
>
> $\Lambda$(“lambda”) factor loading matrix (consisting of the same ’s
> from the measurement model) $\Psi$(“psi”) variance-covariance matrix
> of the latent factors (i.e., variance of; for one factor, it is a
> scalar) $\Theta_\epsilon$(“theta-epsilon”) variance-covariance matrix
> of the residuals
>
> The dimensions of this matrix correspond to the same as that of the
> observed covariance matrix , for three items it is 3 x 3. Recall that
> the model covariance matrix can be defined by the following in the
> three item one-factor case: $\Sigma(\theta) =
> \begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\\lambda_2\\\lambda_3\\\end{pmatrix} \Psi (\lambda_1 \lambda_3 \lambda_3)$

In this case it would then be $\Lambda \Xi \Lambda{^t} + \Theta$ Where $\Xi$ is the covariance matrix of $\xi$. As such the dimensions result in a 25000x25000 matrix which is obviously incorrect. The final calculation should result in a 5x5 matrix. This leads me to believe that there is something wrong in my logic in understanding the basis of the variables.

Off the top of my head I can see a few places where my misunderstanding comes from at the moment.

1. **Y's dimensionality**. Maybe Y is a p x 1 matrix. If this is the case then I am confused as to how CFA can have multiple items then it seems like y needs to be pxn.
2. $\xi$ dimensionality. Maybe $\xi$ is a scalar? However, then when we calculate its covariance we just get zero so that seems wrong. Secondly if we just use that scalar value in the calculation even assuming Y is px1 then we still don't output a 5x5 matrix.
3. The $F_{ml}$ formula from the wiki forces the matrices to the correct dimensions. I guess it is possible this is the case, and I am overlooking something here. If this occurs can you also explain the dimensionality of $\Lambda$ and $\Omega$.

I appreciate any assistance.